# Android - Google Play Store closes app for update and not opening it afterwards

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

I've got the following situation: My app is always running on my Android device. Because I want to be able to update it automatically I've activated Google Play Store auto-updates.

When Play store recognizes the new version I closes my app (what is ok) and updates it (great!). Unfortunately afterwards the app is not opened again.

Does anybody know a solution or has an idea how I can tell my app, the store or the device to open my app again?

BTW: My app starts on system start-up. So rebooting the devide would be a possibility as well. But how to I catch the `update-finished` event?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I build the app. It has a listener for the system startup so it is started on boot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android In App Update not installing APK after downloading APK in immediate mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553644/android-in-app-update-not-installing-apk-after-downloading-apk-in-immediate-mode)

Comment: @AnthonyCannon Seems like a different question.  That's about not installing, this is about installing, but not reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post Honeycomb, apps have to be started manually by the user after installation or upgrade.

If you need your app to always run continuously, you would need to turn off auto update and manually update it yourself so that you can launch it manually after updating.

Comment: oh really? that would be a shame! So is there maybe a way to restart the device after updating?

Comment: No. You cannot do that. You only need to start the app manually the first time. After this it will respond to intents etc normally. It is a security feature so that malicious code cannot be automatically run.

Comment: ok, good to know. unfortunately I'm forced to have a solution which doesn't require manual interaction...