# Immediate In-App Update on Android 10 and above closes the app after install/restart

Tags: java, android, in-app-update

Have implemented Immediate In-App Update Workflow in my android app but have been observing this weird behaviour where after downloading/installing the app update, the api does not restart the app UI (have confirmed that the app is activated in the background) only on Android 10 and above. For Android 9 and below, the app is restarted and app UI is activated again all fine.

Is this the expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Using the following version for the play core library:
`implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0"`

and followed the official documentation for IMMEDIATE in-App update here - https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, still no solution!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Google Play Store closes app for update and not opening it afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402878/android-google-play-store-closes-app-for-update-and-not-opening-it-afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and after 2 days I added

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

to the launcher Activity And I used

```
ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(this)
```

From ProcessPhoenix library in OnActivityResult And then the app restarted after updating.